# reactjs - unmount navbar-dropdown on close

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am using a bootstrap-react nav as seen in the following:

```
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg" className="navbar">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand className="edowl-title small-scale"> <Link to={"/"}>title</Link></Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="me-auto">

              <NavDropdown className="Main-element tiny-scale" title="Updates" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                <Updates/>
              </NavDropdown>

              <NavDropdown className="Main-element tiny-scale" title="Notes" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                <QuickNotes/>
              </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
```

When the second dropdown updates is loaded it will run a request to get all "updates"

```
    const [updates, setUpdates] = useState([])
    const [{ tokens }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const[errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadUpdates = async () => {
            try {
                const post_request = await Axios({
                    method: "get",
                    url: `${window.ipAddress.ip}/Update/Recent`,
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": `Bearer ${tokens.access_token}` }
                })

                console.log(post_request)
                if (post_request.status === 200) {
                    setUpdates(post_request.data)
                }
                else { setErrorMsg("Couldnt complete") }
            }
            catch (err) {
                if (err) {
                    setErrorMsg(err)
                }
            }
        }
        loadUpdates();
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (updates.length <= 0) {
            var todayDate = new Date();
            var todayDateText = todayDate.getDate() + "/" + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + todayDate.getFullYear()

            console.log(todayDateText);
            setUpdates([{ content: "There is currently no new updates", generatedDate: todayDateText, id: 1 }])
        }
    },[updates])

    return (
        <div className="update-container">
            <ul className="update-list">
                {updates.map((update, index) => (
                    <li key={index} className="update-element"><p>{update?.generatedDate} - {update?.content}</p></li>
                ))}

            </ul>
        </div>
    );
```

Obviously because it only runs the request on mount, that means when you close the menu and re-open it, it wont re-execute the request.

My question is how can I make this component unmount on minimizing it?

^ so that when it is re-opened, it will remount and the request will once again execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easy way to go about doing what you want is to manage a counter or a Boolean toggle in the NavBar component, Then you can use the onToggle prop in the NavBar.Collapse to update that value. Have that value passed into your Updates component then use that value in the dependency array inside of the useEffect you want to be triggered each time the navBar Toggles: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors

Comment: It wouldnt be a terrible idea, but i have multiple navs based on user roles, meaning its a lot of code repetition over something like just un-mounting from inside the component

Comment: Does the url change? you can monitor the url and set that as the dependency, then if the url changes it would trigger an update. Though you may have the issue of these updating when you don't want to because they would change on every url but then you don't have to do it everywhere. You can build a wrapper that has the logic in it and passes it to the children so you can build the 1 component then just wrap the components you want to have this logic.